# Change the size of angular material checkbox (mat-checkbox)

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular-material, css-transforms

I'm trying to increase the size of the material checkbox.

`transform` seems to increase the size of the material checkbox. However, I'm not sure if this is a correct way to achieve that?

**CSS**

```
 ::ng-deep .mat-checkbox .mat-checkbox-frame {
     transform: scale(2);
 }

 ::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-checked .mat-checkbox-background {
     transform: scale(2);
 }
```

Comment: `::ng-deep` is deprecated https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Comment: Thanks what could be a reasonable thing to do then?

Comment: This issue is still a very-much open debate, see:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25160

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As `::ng-deep` is deprecated, you can:

Add `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in your `@Component` like:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

And in your CSS simply use this:

```
.mat-checkbox .mat-checkbox-frame {
     transform: scale(2);
}

.mat-checkbox-checked .mat-checkbox-background {
     transform: scale(2);
}
```

Comment: Something seems to be missing there. Unchecking the checkbox will make the "checked state" appear in regular size for a short amount of time. So when unchecking, you'll see a smaller version of the "checked" icon inside the checkbox.

Comment: @displayname Thanks for pointing that out. I added the missing classes below in case anyone needs the solution.

Answer (score 7):

The edit Queue for the correct answer is full. So I added the missing classes here to get rid of the unchecking and checking Animation problem.

```css
.mat-checkbox-frame,
.mat-checkbox-background,
.mat-checkbox-anim-unchecked-checked
.mat-checkbox-anim-checked-unchecked {
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

Comment: Are you missing a comma after ```mat-checkbox-anim-unchecked-checked```?

Answer (score 0):

This is the best answer worked for me

```
.my-checkbox {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}

.my-checkbox .mat-ripple-element {
    transform: translate(0, 0), scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    left: 0 !important;
    top: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In Angular 16 you can set the CSS variable `--mdc-checkbox-state-layer-size` to a certain size:

```
:root {
  --mdc-checkbox-state-layer-size: 80px;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't change the checkbox size. It changes the height of the entire row.